# первые два элемента выдает undefined в массиве после цикла

Tags: javascript

Есть массив с вопросами. Оттуда я пытаюсь взять правильные ответы. При цикле массива он возвращяет массив с правильными ответами но первые два элемента undefined. вопрос почему? Если вопросы местами поменять все равно выдает первые два элемента undefined.
Вот массив

```
const arr = [
{
    "title": "First test",
    "questions": [
        {
            "description": "Сколько дней составляет «Гарантированный период?",
            "alternatives": [
                {
                    "isCorrect": false,
                    "text": "40"
                },
                {
                    "isCorrect": false,
                    "text": "60"
                },
                {
                    "isCorrect": true,
                    "text": "30"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "description": "Сколько дней составляет «Гарантированный период?",
            "alternatives": [
                {
                    "isCorrect": false,
                    "text": "40"
                },
                {
                    "isCorrect": false,
                    "text": "60"
                },
                {
                    "isCorrect": true,
                    "text": "30"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "description": "Сколько дней составляет «Гарантированный период?",
            "alternatives": [
                {
                    "isCorrect": false,
                    "text": "40"
                },
                {
                    "isCorrect": false,
                    "text": "60"
                },
                {
                    "isCorrect": true,
                    "text": "30"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
];
```

вот код

```
const getAnswers = (array) => {
let data = array
let arr1 = [];
let arr2 = [''];

for(x in data){
arr1.push(data[x].alternatives);
}

for(y in arr1){
let arr = arr1[y];
arr2 = arr.map((item, index) => {
  if(item.isCorrect === true) {
    return item.text;
  }
})
}
return arr2;
}

console.log(getAnswers(arr[0].questions));
```

в output вы дает [ undefined, undefined, '30' ]

Comment: Что Вы хотите сделать, и какой ожидаете результат?

Comment: @Igor я хочу чтобы при цикле массива он возвращял правильные ответы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
let arr2 = [];
for(y in arr1) {
  arr2.push(arr1[y].find(item => item.isCorrect).text);
}
return arr2;
```

```js
const arr = [{
  "title": "First test",
  "questions": [{
      "description": "Сколько дней составляет «Гарантированный период 1?",
      "alternatives": [{
          "isCorrect": false,
          "text": "40"
        },
        {
          "isCorrect": false,
          "text": "60"
        },
        {
          "isCorrect": true,
          "text": "31"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "Сколько дней составляет «Гарантированный период 2?",
      "alternatives": [{
          "isCorrect": false,
          "text": "40"
        },
        {
          "isCorrect": false,
          "text": "60"
        },
        {
          "isCorrect": true,
          "text": "32"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "Сколько дней составляет «Гарантированный период 3?",
      "alternatives": [{
          "isCorrect": false,
          "text": "40"
        },
        {
          "isCorrect": false,
          "text": "60"
        },
        {
          "isCorrect": true,
          "text": "33"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}];

const getAnswers = (array) => {
  let data = array
  let arr1 = [];

  for (x in data) {
    arr1.push(data[x].alternatives);
  }

  let arr2 = [];
  for (y in arr1) {
    arr2.push(arr1[y].find(item => item.isCorrect).text);
  }
  return arr2;
}

console.log(getAnswers(arr[0].questions));
```

Comment: все заработало. Теперь буду брать во внимание метод find(). спасибо